# Como puedo hacer una validacion personalizada con la clase Serializer en DJANGO REST FRAMEWORK

Tags: python, django-models, djangorestframework, crud, serialización

Estoy haciendo un CRUD a una base de datos con django rest, tengo una relacion many-to-many en dos de mis modelos.

```
class Contrato(models.Model):
    contrato = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.contrato

class Actividades_especificas_contrato(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    contrato = models.ManyToManyField(Contrato, related_name='contratos', verbose_name="Contrato: ")
    actividad_especifica = models.TextField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.actividad_especifica
```

Tengo unos CSV con los datos que quiero meter, en cada modelo, como los modelos los actualizo individualmente no tengo relaciones anidadas en mis Serializers.

```
class Contratos_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Contrato
        fields = '__all__'
class Actividades_especificas_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Actividades_especificas_contrato
        fields = '__all__'
```

Primero tengo una API que introduce mi primer modelo Contrato, luego tengo esta que introduce las actividades:

```
class Introduce_actividad(APIView):
    # POST API
    def post(self,request):
        serializer = Actividades_especificas_serializer(data = request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        actividad = serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

los datos los introduzco iterando el CSV y llegan a la API de la siguiente manera:

```
data = {
    'id': 123,
    'contrato': [1,2,3,4],
    'actividad_especifica': 'Hacer papeleo en la empresa ...'

}
```

En este objeto, contrato es una lista que tiene las llaves primarias del  modelo Contrato.
El problema es que en la base de datos, falta alguno de los id de los contratos guardados en esta lista, manda un error y la actividad falla al ser introducida en la base de datos.

```
{"contrato":["Invalid pk \"3\" - object does not exist."]}
```

Mi pregunta es, hay alguna manera que en el proceso de validación de los datos, al encontrar este error,  simplemente omita el id de este contrato y cree la actividad asociándola solo a los contratos que si están en la base de datos.